# 2016 12" MacBook won't turn on

Tags: macbook-pro, startup

So, I had my 12 inch MacBook plugged into an external monitor (with Bluetooth keyboard and mouse) and was working on it normally, when suddenly everything became really slow and unresponsive, after waiting for a while for Force Quit to work and with nothing happening I decided to force shut-down the machine.

When it was starting up it asked me for a password after entering it the login screen froze after waiting for 5 min I force shutdown this as well.

But now the machine just won't turn on at all. What can I do?

Comment: If it won't turn on at all, there's really nothing you can do other than take it to Apple in for service.  Just to clarify, when you say it won't turn on, it does *nothing* when you hit the power button; the screen stays black.

Comment: Yes dos nothing the screen is black

Comment: Long shot:  Reset the [SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) (Different procedure depending on Mac Model) Hold `Shift-Ctrl-Option-Pwr` at the same time for 10 seconds while unplugged.  Plug back in.  If still dead, time for service.

Comment: When you reset the SMC, make sure to unplug every wired device, like a external display, USB drive, etc. BTW/ have you tried to restart with the external display detached?

Comment: I had the exact same problem, under the exact same circumstances – resetting the SMC worked.

Comment: Yes SMC reset worked for me as well!

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by doing an SMC reset.